# Customized navigation bar buttons freezing after stand by

Tags: ios, ipad

I am having a strange problem.I have used customized navigation bar(for which I have used another ViewController separately) in my project which has ofcourse navigation buttons.
As the device becomes active after stand by,it normally becomes active in portrait mode by default. And if we have held the device in some other orientation,it rotates to that orientation and every thing works fine. Even the navigation bar buttons.

Now here is the problem. If the device is held in Portrait mode after stand by,it freezes the navigation  bar buttons. As far as I have concluded,this is because the application gets active in portrait mode by default and since the device is also held in Portrait mode,it can not find any orientation to rotate and hence freezes the buttons.Except navigation bar buttons,everything works fine.And if I rotate the device,like I have said,Everything works fine.

Dont have any idea,why this is happening.Can someone explain?

Comment: sorry I forgot mentioning its an iPad app.